# How to add a `avatar` field when using `Auth` of laravel 5.3 out of the box?

Tags: php, laravel

How to add a `avatar` field when using  `Auth` of  laravel `5.3` out of the box?
I  do it like this and there is an error:

1、I add a `avatar` filed in table 'users'.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('avatar');  // add a `avatar` filed
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

2、add a defalut value of `avatar` in create() method of `\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php`

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'avatar'=> '/images/avatar.png',  //add a defalut value of `avatar`
    ]);
}
```

Then,test register,there is an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'avatar' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (user01, user01@example.com, $2y$10$z4wtbQWbqU00000, 2016-12-07 19:31:09, 2016-12-07 19:31:09))
```

I debug it and the error occurs in this line below of `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php`,as follow:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));  //the error occurs in this line 

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: did you execute the migration before trying to save the user?

Comment: @rotvulpix No,I executed the migration after adding it to the table.there is `avatar` field in `users` table .

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you executed the migration before you added it to the table, or you have existing fields in your users table, but the avatar is not nullable.
what you should do in a clean way:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

This will, well, rollback your last batch of migrations.
now, you would need to add the avatar like so, in your users migration:

```
$table->string('avatar')->nullable();
```

now its should be properly configured.

Comment: No,I executed the migration after adding it to the table.there is `avatar` field in `users` table .

Comment: @zwl1619 did you added the avatar field to the `validator` function in you RegisterController?